# Subtotals in Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I am trying to add a subtotal row in the access results like the Total row below. Is there a way to do it in the query design view? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: This is something that you would normally do in a report by putting the subtotals in a group footer.

Comment: How do I do that? The screen shot I attached is the result of a query.

Comment: Use the Report Wizard based on your existing query, add grouping as required, and then add the subtotal as a calculated field in a text box in the appropriate group footer.

Comment: And how did you produce that screenshot? If that is your work and the result you want, exactly what is the issue? Report Sorting & Grouping with aggregate calcs is basic Access functionality. I am sure you can find a tutorial. Any introductory book should have a chapter.

Comment: It was a screen shot given to me. I haven't been able to find anything that says how to do it.

Comment: Doing it in query would involve building two queries then another UNION query with those two https://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/935950-how-do-i-subtotal-grand-total-query. Report is better https://www.techwalla.com/articles/how-to-create-totals-subtotals-in-microsoft-access